# Is there a way to improve the speed or efficiency of this lookup? (C/C++)

Tags: c++, optimization, lookup, modulo

I have a function I've written to convert from a 64-bit integer to a base 62 string. Originally, I achieved this like so:

```
char* charset = " 0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
int charsetLength = strlen(charset);

std::string integerToKey(unsigned long long input)
{
    unsigned long long num = input;
    string key = "";

    while(num)
    {
        key += charset[num % charsetLength];
        num /= charsetLength;
    }

    return key;
}
```

However, this was too slow.

I improved the speed by providing an option to generate a lookup table. The table is about 62<sup>4</sup> strings in size, and is generated like so:

```
// Create the integer to key conversion lookup table
int lookupChars;

if(lookupDisabled)
    lookupChars = 1;
else
    largeLookup ? lookupChars = 4 : lookupChars = 2;

lookupSize = pow(charsetLength, lookupChars);
integerToKeyLookup = new char*[lookupSize];

for(unsigned long i = 0; i < lookupSize; i++)
{
    unsigned long num = i;
    int j = 0;

    integerToKeyLookup[i] = new char[lookupChars];

    while(num)
    {
        integerToKeyLookup[i][j] = charset[num % charsetLength];
        num /= charsetLength;

        j++;
    }

    // Null terminate the string
    integerToKeyLookup[i][j] = '\0';
}
```

The actual conversion then looks like this:

```
std::string integerToKey(unsigned long long input)
{
    unsigned long long num = input;
    string key = "";

    while(num)
    {
        key += integerToKeyLookup[num % lookupSize];
        num /= lookupSize;
    }

    return key;
}
```

This improved speed by a large margin, but I still believe it can be improved. Memory usage on a 32-bit system is around 300 MB, and more than 400 MB on a 64-bit system. It seems like I should be able to reduce memory and/or improve speed, but I'm not sure how.

If anyone could help me figure out how this table could be further optimized, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: In your first version, I think `key /= charsetLength;` should be `num /= charsetLength;`.

Comment: Not related to your main problem, but you probably want to declare charset as `const`.

Comment: @sbi: But it's so much fun to try to optimize an infinite loop.

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. I rewrote this code from memory just to serve as an illustration of how I was doing things in my application. I'll fix that.

Comment: [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) will be much faster, and there are already many optimized libraries for this

Comment: If you can add 2 more symbols to your charset it would speed it up significantly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with Rob Walker - you're concentrating on improving performance in the wrong area.  The string is the slowest part.

I timed the code (your original is broken, btw) and your original (when fixed) was 44982140 cycles for 100000 lookups and the following code is about 13113670.

```
const char* charset = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
#define CHARSET_LENGTH 62

// maximum size = 11 chars
void integerToKey(char result[13], unsigned long long input)
{
    char* p = result;
    while(input > 0)
    {
        *p++ = charset[input % CHARSET_LENGTH];
        input /= CHARSET_LENGTH;
    }

    // null termination
    *p = '\0';
    // need to reverse the output
    char* o = result;
    while(o + 1 < p)
        swap(*++o, *--p);
}
```

Comment: If performance is really critical, the only change I'd made to this is to eliminate the % operator.  This can be very slow depending upon your CPU for a 64 bit number.  It would be substantially faster to perform the division and subtract the new value of input from the old value of input to calculate the index in charset.  This could speed things up over 30%

Comment: @Stephen Nutt - Did you actually time that?  The x86 can do a single instruction divide with remainder of a 64-bit number.  I would expect the compiler to just use that.

Comment: if you look at [Agner Fog's optimization](http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf) then 8-bit division on x86 is fastest while 64-bit division may be 5 times slower depending on the architecture. That's because division cannot be parallellized like addition, subtraction or multiplication

Comment: anyway, an optimized compiler will convert a division/modulus by a constant like your code (but not the OP's version) into multiplication and you won't notice the difference using 32 or 64-bit arithmetics

Answer (score 6):

Using some kind of string builder rather than repeated concatenation into 'key' would provide a significant speed boost.

Comment: In the STL this would probably be an `std::ostringstream`.

Comment: I'd avoid streams; they are slow to create and destroy.  A char array of 12 characters would be sufficient.

Comment: std::basic_string (std::string is just a typedef of this class) has a function "reserve" which assures there is enough memory for specified number of characters to avoid later allocations and copying. In this case the number of characters is known fixed so you could even use resize and then instead of adding characters with += use indexing directly.

Answer (score 6):

You may want to reserve memory in advance for your `string key`.  This may get you a decent performance gain, as well as a gain in memory utilization.  Whenever you call the append operator on `std::string`, it may double the size of the internal buffer if it has to reallocate.  This means each string may be taking up significantly more memory than is necessary to store the characters.  You can avoid this by reserving memory for the string in advance.

Comment: I actually forgot to mention that I've already reserved space for the string. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 2):

This is almost a textbook case of how not to do this. Concatenating strings in a loop is a bad idea, both because appending isn't particularly fast, and because you're constantly allocating memory.

Note: your question states that you're converting to base-62, but the code seems to have 63 symbols. Which are you trying to do?

Given a 64-bit integer, you can calculate that you won't need any more than 11 digits in the result, so using a static 12 character buffer will certainly help improve your speed. On the other hand, it's likely that your C++ library has a long-long equivalent to ultoa, which will be pretty optimal.

---

Edit: Here's something I whipped up. It allows you to specify any desired base as well:

```
std::string ullToString(unsigned long long v, int base = 64) {
    assert(base < 65);
    assert(base > 1);
    static const char digits[]="0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ+/";
    const int max_length=65;
    static char buffer[max_length];

    buffer[max_length-1]=0;
    char *d = buffer + max_length-1;
    do {
        d--;
        int remainder = v % base;
        v /= base;
        *d = digits[remainder];
    } while(v>0);

    return d;
}
```

This only creates one std::string object, and doesn't move memory around unnecessarily. It currently doesn't zero-pad the output, but it's trivial to change it to do that to however many digits of output you want.

Comment: ultoa() would be great exept the radix is limited to 2 - 36.

Comment: I know I've seen versions that accepted higher bases, as an extension. But it shouldn't be all that hard to write, anyway.

Comment: Static buffer is a bad idea, somebody would call it from multiple threads

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to copy input into num, because you pass it by value.  You can also compute the length of charset in compiletime, there's no need to compute it in runtime every single time you call the function.

But these are very minor performance issues.  I think the the most significant help you can gain is by avoiding the string concatenation in the loop.  When you construct the key string pass the string constructor the length of your result string so that there is only one allocation for the string.  Then in the loop when you concatenate into the string you will not re-allocate.

You can make things even slightly more efficient if you take the target string as a reference parameter or even as two iterators like the standard algorithms do.  But that is arguably a step too far.

By the way, what if the value passed in for input is zero?  You won't even enter the loop; shouldn't key then be "0"?

I see the value passed in for input can't be negative, but just so we note: the C remainder operator isn't a modulo operator.

Answer (score 1):

If you could add two more symbols so that it is converting to base-64, your modulus and division operations would turn into a bit mask and shift. Much faster than a division.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is a short string key, converting to base-64 numbers would speed up things a lot, since div/mod 64 is very cheap (shift/mask).

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a base64 library? Is really important that 63 equals '11' and not a longer string?

```
size_t base64_encode(char* outbuffer, size_t maxoutbuflen, const char* inbuffer, size_t inbuflen);

std::string integerToKey(unsigned long long input) {
    char buffer[14];
    size_t len = base64_encode(buffer, sizeof buffer, (const char*)&input, sizeof input);
    return std::string(buffer, len);
}
```

Yes, every string will end with an equal size. If you don't want it to, strip off the equal sign. (Just remember to add it back if you need to decode the number.)

Of course, my real question is why are you turning a fixed width 8byte value and not using it directly as your "key" instead of the variable length string value?

Footnote: I'm well aware of the endian issues with this. He didn't say what the key will be used for and so I assume it isn't being used in network communications between machines of disparate endian-ness.